# Why would Batman discard his disruptor?

Tags: character, the-dark-knight-rises, batman-begins

During the chase sequence in which Batman reveals himself during *The Dark Knight Rises*, there is a sequence when Batman uses a pump action disruptor weapon against Bane's getaway motorcade.

[image]

Moments after we see how useful this weapon is, a rookie cop shoots the weapon, disabling it:

[image]

The next part really puzzles me: *Batman throws the weapon down*.

It's obviously useless to him: but he's just given over a piece of evidence to them, which seems hugely uncharacteristic of the Nolan-Verse Batman SOP.

During the Dark Knight Rises, his Tumbler even self-destructs after the Batpod is ejected, presumably to destroy any evidence that would link the vehicle to Wayne Enterprises.

[image]

I realize that he gifts a [Young Joffrey](http://img233.imageshack.us/img233/3720/joffrey.jpg) with a surveillance device during the Batman Begins, but I think given the police attention these are different circumstances.

I also accept that the moment is funny, and understand it to be a nod to the audience that Nolan isn't going to let batman use his 'gadgets' to pull victory out of his a$!%hole, like times of yore...

[image]

But I still don't understand why he would throw the device down. It just seems incredibly sloppy for what has been typically methodical execution.

**Does anyone have any insight on this?**

Comment: If he threw away the EMP gun it probably would be crushed by traffic, so it wouldn't be traced back to Wayne Enterprises. In the overall context of the story it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have just rewatched the scene, and the disruptor is not thrown away. He lowers it gun, putting it next to his right leg, where it was at the beginning of the scene.

In movies, if a gun is disposed off willingly, it is usually (always?) dramatically thrown away, and not just gently dropped next to one's leg.

Besides, here it is, mere 20 seconds later, attached and shining where it was in the first place:

[image: The disruptor is here]

Later, we don't see the disruptor anymore, for example right before the end of the chase:

[image: The disruptor is gone]

I see it as just one of many "the item (dis)appears when it is (not) needed" moments, typical for the Batman and his gadgets throughout all of his movies and series.

Comment: Watch again: The disruptor is clearly visible on the back right hand side of his bike (it's even charged up and glowing). After he discards it, it's no longer there. I'm aware that guns are disposed of in action movies, but this is missing the point of the question: the gun is Wayne Tech that could link Batman to Bruce Wayne.. so far he's been overt in concealing this connection entirely..

Comment: And the gun is **Definately** shot! there is a bullet pock mark on the right hand side of the * Barrrel * that isn't there in any of the shots prior to the gunshot, and he makes a point of looking forlornly at the gun before staring at the cop...that's the essence of the joke

Comment: *typical for the Batman and his gadgets throughout all of his movies and series*... could you justify this statement, please? everything I can find (particularily in the Nolanverse Batman) seems to indicate the exact opposite of this..

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional For example, the grappling hook gun... where does he keep that? In his pocket? It's not a small thing to hide. Don't get me wrong, I don't mind it. I just don't see that the disruptor that suddenly went missing is a problem.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional You are right about the disruptor getting shot. However, it is **not** thrown away. Please, see my edit.

Comment: You're right about him not throwing it away, so I'm giving it to you. I hadn't realized it's shown in shot on the back of the bike later, I guess him putting it by his right knee instead of where he got it from kind of threw me. This answers my question,but leaves me with more questions: although I imagine the answers to those to be continuity based.